# Rust-Lexical: Parsing float with thousand and digit separator

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to parse a Rust string into a Rust float. I have a number with trailing blanks inside a character string. This number may have a comma as a thousand separator and a dot as a decimal separator. Standard Rust trips over a comma.

```
fn main() {

    let s: String = "   65,536.1415926535   ".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);

    let f: f64    = s.trim().parse::<f64>().unwrap();
    println!("{}", f);
}

==>

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseFloatError { kind: Invalid }', src/main.rs:6:45
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I'm trying to build a custom Parser with Lexical, but I cannot make sense of Lexical's documentation. I know I should be able to delete all commas prior to parsing, but I'm looking for a clean and elegant solution that will work with commas.

**Update**

Here is my attempt to use standard Lexical. It hiccups at the same spot:

```
use lexical;

fn main() {

    let s: String = "   65,536.1415926535   ".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);

    let f: f64    = lexical::parse( s.trim() ).unwrap();
    println!("{}", f);
}

==>

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidDigit(2)', src/main.rs:8:48
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

**Finally**
Adapting the [official Lexical example](https://docs.rs/lexical/latest/lexical/#example) on building a custom parser fails as well:

```
use lexical;
use lexical_core;

fn main() {

    const BRITISH: f64 = lexical::NumberFormatBuilder::new()
        .digit_separator(b',')
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let options = lexical_core::ParseFloatOptions::builder()
        .decimal_point(b'.')
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let s: String = "   65,536.1415926535   ".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);

    let f: f64    = lexical::parse_with_options::<f64, BRITISH, _>( s.trim(), &options ).unwrap();
    println!("{}", f);
}

==>

error[E0599]: no method named `digit_separator` found for struct `NumberFormatBuilder` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:10
  |
6 |       const BRITISH: f64 = lexical::NumberFormatBuilder::new()
  |  __________________________-
7 | |         .digit_separator(b',')
  | |         -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  | |         ||
  | |         |private field, not a method
  | |_________|help: there is a method with a similar name: `get_digit_separator`
  |

error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected
  --> src/main.rs:19:56
   |
19 |     let f: f64    = lexical::parse_with_options::<f64, BRITISH, _>( s.trim(), &options ).unwrap();
```

Comment: IMHO the most simple and elegant solution is to trim and delete all commas. Its only problem is its performance, which shouldn't be a problem most of the cases.

Comment: Their example is flawed. It requires the `format` feature but doesn't compile even with it. After three required changes, it does compile, but it looks like while they advertise supporting for separators in floats, they only really support fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly removing the commas is the *simplest* solution:

```
fn main() {

    let s: String = "   65,536.1415926535   ".to_string();
    println!("{}", s);

    let f: f64    = s.trim().replace(",","").parse().unwrap();
    println!("{}", f);
}

==>

65,536.1415926535
65536.1415926535
```